# BeautifulSoup - different result lengths

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

from

```
url = 'https://www.example.com/MOVxxxx/YYYY-MM-DD'
```

i am using loop on the page with range (the xxx = ID MOV) & (date)

```
for page1 in mov_pages:
    for page2 in date_pages:
        response = get('https://www.example.com + page1 + '/' + page2)
        page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        containers_1 = page_html.find_all('ul', class_='showtime-lists')
        containers_2 = page_html.find_all('div', class_='day')
```

the html structure like this:

```
<ul class="showtime-lists">
    <li>...</li>
        <format="2D" movie="3247" time="12.00"
    <li>...</li>
        <format="2D" movie="3247" time="13.30"
    <li>...</li>
        ...
```

and in another structure (same page)

```
<div class="day">
    <a href date="2017-10-15">..</a>
<div class="day">
    <a href date="2017-10-15">..</a>
...
```

My purpose is to create dataframe from lists with format like this:

```
date        time    movie
2017-10-14  12.00   3247
2017-10-14  13.30   3247
2017-10-14  12.00   3252
...
2017-10-15
2017-10-15
...     ... ...
```

the problem is :

```
* the structure given different lengths
```

My best trial :

```
* I can create the df with time&movie correctly but not the date (because the date didnt have the same length)
```

My Code :

```
    #extract movie & time was similar way
    movie = []  
    for container in containers_1:
            idx = container['movie']
            movie.append(idx)

    #extract date
    date_id = []
        for each in containers_2:
        date_idx = each.a['date']
        date_id.append(date_idx)
```

OUTPUT :

```
movie&time had same length but not with date
```

Comment: What do you mean by the structures have different lenghts? If it's sure that there are the same number of `<div class="day">` as  `<li>...</li>
        <format="2D" movie="3247" time="12.00"`(...), then I can write a code that helps you.

Comment: Sorry for make you confused, I mean different lengths is different number of  <div class="day"> and <li>...</li> <format="2D" movie="3247" time="12.00". (Each date:"2017-10-15"  can contains many time: "12.00","13.00",etc.